# How to add a custom filter for use in a cookiecutter template?

Tags: python, jinja2, template-engine, cookiecutter

how can I add a custom filter to be used in a jinja template used by cookiecutter?

I tried adding using a pre_gen_project hook, it's called, but I can't find a way to make my python functions visible as jinja filters (or function) inside the templates.

Comment: Have you read the jinja2 [docs](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/#writing-filters)?

Comment: Yes, using the filter decorators didn't work nor adding to a new enviroment's filter dict. I must be missing something.

Comment: you should show your filter code and how you call your filter in jinja2 env

Comment: This is possible using local extensions.
See https://cookiecutter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/local_extensions.html